# friend not allowed outside of a class definition

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to ovrerload the cout operator in an assignment and I was forced and asked to split my class into (.h and .cpp). Here is my full code:

### instructor.h

```
#include "person.h"
#ifndef instructor_h
#define instructor_h
class instructor: public person {

private:    
    int children;
    int salary;
    string maritalStatus;

public:

    instructor();
    instructor(string, string, string, int , int ,string);

instructor operator++();

    void print();



    int calcSalary();

    int getSalary();
    int getNumOfChildren();
    string getMarialStatus();

    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream, instructor );
    void setSalary(int);
    void getNumOfChildren(int);
    void setMarialStatus(string);

};

#endif
```

### instructor.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "instructor.h"
using namespace std;

instructor::instructor() {

}


instructor::instructor(string a , string b, string c , int chil , int sal ,string mar):person(a,b,c) 

{
    children = chil;
    salary = sal;
    maritalStatus = mar;
}


instructor instructor::operator ++()
    {
        children=children+1;
        return *this;
    }


int instructor::calcSalary() {

    int new_sal;
    new_sal = salary + children*0.1;

    return new_sal;
}

int instructor::getSalary() {

    cout <<"Here is the result of your query:"<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout<< "Salary: "<<salary<<""<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout <<endl;

    return salary;


}

int instructor::getNumOfChildren() {

    cout <<"Here is the result of your query:"<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout<< "Number of children: "<<children<<""<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;


    cout <<endl;
    return children;


}

string instructor::getMarialStatus() {

    cout <<"Here is the result of your query:"<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout<< "Marital Status: "<<maritalStatus<<""<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout <<endl;

    return maritalStatus;

}


friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, instructor& v){
    os << v.children;

return os;
}



void instructor::setSalary(int sal) {

    salary = sal;
}

void instructor::getNumOfChildren(int nmc) {

    children = nmc;

}

void instructor::setMarialStatus(string sms) {

    maritalStatus = sms;

}



void instructor::print() {

    person::print();
    cout <<"Here is the result of your query:"<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout<< "Marital Status: "<<maritalStatus<<""<<endl;
    cout<< "Number of children: "<<children<<""<<endl;
    cout<< "Salary: "<<salary<<""<<endl;
    cout <<"================================="<<endl;
    cout <<endl;


}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> **instructor.cpp(75) :** error C2255: 'friend' : not allowed outside of a class definition
>   **instructor.cpp(76) :** error C2248: 'instructor::children' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class 'instructor' 1>
>   c:\documents and settings\george\my documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\hana\hana\instructor.h(7) : see declaration of
>   'instructor::children' 1>
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I am using visual studio 2005. Why am I getting those errors?

All of this is cause by my  attempt in overloading the operator cout:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, instructor& v){
    os << v.children;

return os;
}
```

Why is not working?

Comment: Remove `friend` from the .cpp file

Comment: You share your secrets with friends, but you chose your friends. You do not necessarily share your secrets with people who call themselves your friend. Except for Tom. He's everybody's friend.

Comment: Now, that you seem to have an answer: somewhat by convention, *instructor::operator ++()* should return a *reference* to the incremented object. You are returning a *copy*

Comment: "I'm trying to ovrerload the cout operator " -- no. `std::cout` is not an operator; it's an object. What you're trying to overload is the **stream inserter** `operator<<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that you can't use `friend` outside a class, as the error says. But you don't need to; having declared the function as a friend within the class you just define it outside without having to mention the friend-ness again.

But the other problem is that your declaration and definition don't match. You declared this as a friend:

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream, instructor );
```

And then you defined this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, instructor&)
```

Those aren't the same, but they need to be.